# Unable to get allocation size using !heap -stat -h command

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, windbg

Simulating user mode native memory leak using c++ program, used gflags to enable page heap. Took process memory dump. Following this article https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31382/Memory-Leak-Detection-Using-Windbg, however unable to get the output of !heap -stat -h command as
size     #blocks     total     ( %) (percent of total busy bytes)

I get the below output, what am I missing?

```
0:002> !heap -stat -h 00000224be780000 
Walking the heap 00000224be780000 .
 0: Heap 00000224be780000
   Flags          00000002 - HEAP_GROWABLE 
   Reserved memory in segments              1020 (k)
   Commited memory in segments              160 (k)
   Virtual bytes (correction for large UCR) 1020 (k)
   Free space                               1 (k) (1 blocks)
   External fragmentation          0% (1 free blocks)
   Virtual address fragmentation   84% (1 uncommited ranges)
   Virtual blocks  0 - total 0 KBytes
   Lock contention 0
   Segments        1

                    Default heap   Front heap       Unused bytes
   Range (bytes)     Busy  Free    Busy   Free     Total  Average 
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
     0 -   1024      145      0      0      0       5126     35
  1024 -   2048       11      1      0      0        346     31
  2048 -   3072        2      0      0      0         64     32
  5120 -   6144        2      0      0      0         78     39
  7168 -   8192        1      0      0      0         32     32
 19456 -  20480        1      0      0      0         40     40
 29696 -  30720        1      0      0      0         32     32
 38912 -  39936        1      0      0      0         40     40
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
  Total              164      1      0      0       5758     35
```

Comment: I am presuming that the dumps was not captured correctly. Debug diag with leak track is crashing when capturing the dump, is there a better way to collect dump and analyze native memory leak?